# Repairing center-pulled brakes

Tags: brakes

My bike has the old center-pulled brakes. Unfortunately the ropes for both brakes (front and back) broke, and I had to replace them. Now the small helper-ropes have no friction anymore on the main rope, resting on the mudguards, and providing almost no pulling power for the second brake. Why do the new ropes not provide friction anymore (aka are too thin), and how can I fix that?
Edit: Photos:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You presumably have cantilever brakes.  How you attach the cables depends on whether the setup uses a "straddle wire" or a "link unit".  Park Tool has a [web page](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cantilever-brake-service) which gives some advice on the details.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: I am using a link unit, and routed the rope correctly. Unfortunately they do not provide enough friction on the rope, thus are quite useless. Pictures will be provided later.

Comment: We can help more when you post clear photos.  Use the "edit" link under your question, to do so.

Comment: It's called a "cable".  It sounds like you have passed the cable through the clamp on the brake arm incorrectly, or lost a washer in the process.

Comment: @arc_lupus I've edited my answer. Check if this helped you.

Comment: All you really need to do here is unbolt the cable and pull out slack, but I would really recommend not attempting this brake work yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Brake cable should go through gap in a screw, that is locked with a nut to the holder, connecting cable pulled by the lever with, as you called, helper. Sometimes a gap for the screw in holder is not circular. If you mis-oriented screw against the hole in holder, it rests outside the hole and does not tighten the cable.

Please, add also the photo of the screw that holds brake cable on the brake arm.
It looks like you have to unscrew that screw, pull more cable and then tight it. Also put a bit of oil on the cable where it goes through circular element.

I strongly advice reading article on adjusting cantilever brake. In short:

1. unscrew adjusting screw on the brake lever housing by 3 turns, secure it with nut.
2. unscrew brake pads holders, push the pads towards wheel as far as possible (this will increase braking force), tighten it a bit
3. unscrew brake cable holder on the brake arm, pull it as far as possible - pads should touch the rim. Tighten the screw.
4. Adjust pads that they are adjacent to the rim, tighten them
5. screw adjusting screw mentioned in pt 1 back.

   6. adjust brake arms position witk screws on the bottom of them.

Comment: Added them, I hope they provide enough information.